# What is the root password of Live USB Stick v 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb

I downloaded the Live USB stick image, booted from USB, pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and got the console screen "`login:`". Now, what is the default password for "root" user? I need to load some kernel modules and mount some filesystems before installing.

Comment: The root account is locked by default. Use sudo . https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try user ubuntu without password(with empty password).
As @Panther said, root account is disabled.
If its not ubuntu but lubuntu or xubuntu try distributive name as user login.

Another way, if you run graphical environment press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and run `xterm`. It will not ask for login. Then `su` and do what you want.